# Reading a space-delimited text file with blanks

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to read a text file which has tab space as delimiter but some values are left blank in it, how do i identify that value is left blank while reading the file. Please check my code below

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(new File("File.dat"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
String temp = br.readLine(); 
while (temp != null) {
    temp = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Please help me in pointing out the values that are left blank.

Comment: What do you mean by `some values are left black in it.`? Please explain

Comment: You read the whole lines from the file. Where are the values, you have problem with?

Comment: Give us an example of the file, and tell us which lines are causing issues.

Comment: You are always going to *miss* the first line of the file because you call `readLine()` again inside your while loop before testing its value.

Comment: The first solution I could think of is to split the string by the tab character and check for zero-length-trimmed string to be skipped. Once there, using The stringbuilder class i'd append each of the final array's elements to get the final string without empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @HunterMcMillen hint:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(new File("File.dat"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
String temp = br.readLine(); 
while (temp != null) {

    String[] tabSeparatedArray = temp.split("\t")
    foreach(String tabElement : tabSeparatedArray){
        if (tabElement.trim().length <= 0){
            //here the element is blank... do whatever you want!!!!
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    temp = br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: There are two _issues_ to consider: that the **last columns are blank** or **all columns are blank**. You need to add more code to consider these cases.

Comment: GLad to help you, but please consider @PaulVargas hint to complete the example.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a CSV file, but instead of commas, are tabs. You can use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for read the file.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.txt"), '\t');
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

The columns with blank value as empty strings in the array.

Or more simple:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.txt"), '\t');
List<String[]> all = reader.readAll();
```